# Replication & Table Partitioning

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, database-partitioning

I want to use table partitioning on daily basis with transnational replication.
My first thought was to create a daily job to create partition and file group for the following day but according to MSDN:

> Transactional and merge replication do not support the following commands: ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION, ALTER PARTITION SCHEME, or the REBUILD WITH PARTITION statement of ALTER INDEX.

Is there any way around this?
Do I need to create all the partitions in advance?

Also, are there any more cons for using table partitioning with replication other than the above?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with partitions?  Even though the documentation says transactional and merge replication do not support those commands, you can still apply those commands to either the published article or the subscriber table.  The changes just won't be replicated.  So if you are trying to implement a sliding window partition switching process for managing large amounts of data in a partitioned table you'll need to have processes in place on both publisher and subscriber side to do that.  Don't forget about the allow_partition_switch setting too on the publisher.

Comment: Basically I have a large table (500 million) and I'm trying to improve the performance of the Select/Delete/Insert. Each day 8 million records are inserted into the DB and 8 are deleted (oldest records). the data is read only. Regarding delete the switch gives a massive improvement to simple delete from a non partitioned table.

Comment: Also, I guess I can create 2 jobs, one for the publisher and one the subscriber or one per subscriber if I have multiple, but I guess I'll have an issue if for some reason the job on the subscriber will fail to run for some reason. In this case I suspect that the replication will fail since that tables won't match exactly

Comment: There should not be a problem with that actually.  We have a process we use to manage millions of day-level rows in tables that are billions of rows big on the OLAP servers, but only millions on the OLTP servers that act as the publishers.  But yes, you will need jobs on both the subscriber and the publisher.